# How to use InlineButton with a ReadOnly field in Odin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, odin-inspector

I have a list of `Record` objects defined as:

```cs
public struct Record{
    [ReadOnly]
    public int id;
    [ReadOnly]
    public string info;
}
```

Since it is a recorded info, I dont want member `id` and `info` being changed, I marked them as `ReadOnly`; `ReadOnly` text field cannot select the content, then I try to add `InlineButton` for `info` member so that I can easily copy the content of member `info`. But `ReadOnlyAttribute` also affect `InlineButton` applied on this member, so the button is disabled.

Is there any other way in odin can display a readonly string of content, and available to add inline button to invoke function to copy? Or maybe is there a way in odin dispaly a readonly content that is selectable and copyable?

Comment: I think there might be some limitations with this extension. you should make a custom editor for that.